# Check if multiple conditions are not true php

Tags: php, operators, string-comparison

I want to check if multiple conditions are true/false with php.
So I have

```
$a = 'hello';
```

In the below I expect to return false as a does = hello

```
var_dump(($a !== 'hello'));
bool(false)
```

this works as expected,

however If I try and ad an or in as shown below it returns true.

```
var_dump(($a !== 'hello')||($a !== 'bye'));
bool(true)
```

Why is this and how can I structure this so that I get false?

Comment: If $a === 'hello' then your second case _is_ true

Comment: u need to use __&&__ instead of __||__.........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use AND. You check if $a isn't hello OR if $a isn't bye. The second one returns true.

```
var_dump($a !== 'hello' && $a !== 'bye');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$a !== 'bye'`...since it is `hello`

$a isn't 'hello' OR $a isn't 'bye'

Well, it isn't 'bye' because it's 'hello'.  Therefore, the test is `true`